# how would the (<map> <key>) calling convention be implemented for js-objects?

Tags: clojurescript

I would like to be able to use `(js-obj)` like a hash-map so that

```
 (def a (js* "{'a': 1, 'b':2}"))

 (a :a)
 ;=> 1
```

I tried doing this:

```
 (extend-type object
   IFn
   (-invoke
     ([o k] (aget o (strkey k))))
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should use `js/Object` instead of `object`?

Comment: oh wow it worked! I was working off the example in here: https://github.com/pangloss/clang/blob/master/client/clang/js_types.cljs

Comment: okay... I realised its not such a great idea.... jquery broke when I did that

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `reify`. Note that means you won't be able to access the properties directly then:

```
(defn convert [obj]
  (reify
    IFn
    (-invoke [obj]
      ([o k] (aget o (strkey k))))))
```

Of course you could write a protocol so you can access the original object if you like.